# 'content_security_policy' in Chrome packaged app not allowed

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome Packaged app for the first time. It will be using the bluetooth api for communicating with a smartphone.

I encountered a problem when trying to implement AngularJS: Apparently the Content Security Policy should be bypassed by declaring it in the manifest file but I get this error:

> 'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

I looked it up and read that the page should be running in a sandbox, does this mean I would no longer have access to the bluetooth adapter?
What are my options for making this work?

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/angular_framework "Unlike many other JS MVC frameworks, Angular v1.1.0+ requires no tweaks to work within a strict CSP. It just works, out of the box!"

Comment: As rsanchez says, if you're running into CSP issues with Angular, you're doing it wrong. There are lots of Chrome Apps using AngularJS just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link and feedback. I forgot the `var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);`

Comment: I got same issue because "angular.js[10243]" (new Function... is forbidden by CSP).